# How to upload multiple files with additional field react.js flask

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, multipartform-data, form-data

I am trying to upload files along with its additional field using react.js and python(flask). User can upload multiple files.
[image]

For add more functionality I am pushing Name and File in an Array and that array is stored in component's state like below.

```
this.state = {
   files:[{name:'', file:''}]
}
```

And I created a rest api in flask to upload files and save data. and passing `this.state` data as `formData()`. And I am trying to get uploaded files in flask like below.

```
let formData = this.state; 
    const fd = new FormData(); 
    for(let k in formData){
        fd.append(k,formData[k]);
    };
```

Rest API-

```
@mod_upload.route('/upload',methods=['POST'])
def upload():
        if request.method == 'POST': 
                f = request.files['files']
                print(f)
```

Everything is working fine but in above code `f` is always empty because in `formData()` I am appending `this.state.files` which is an Array but it expect file Object.

So, I need suggestions, how to access files and fields value in `request.files['files']`.

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: add your upload request code. do you send  proper headers in your http request? `{headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}}`

Comment: Yes, in headers content type is multipart/form-data

Comment: Ok. what is in `request.form` object ?

Comment: `request.form` is an `ImmutableMultiDict` which contains all form data along with `files:[{name:'', file:''}]` also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. Notice the `'files'` key while appending form data. Let me know if it works

UPDATED ANS

```
let formData = this.state; 
    const fd = new FormData(); 
    for(const k of formData){
        fd.append('files',k.file, k.name);
    };
```

Comment: its throwing error `Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'` . I think it expect file as `blob` but I have file as an `object`.

Comment: because we are providing the second parameter as an integer. We need to provide a blob type. Try the updated answer. Also if possible can you add upload logic in your question

Answer (score 2):

you are not sending a file value, so `requests.files['files']` will be empty.

```
fd.append("file", files[0]); // replace files[0] with your file
fd.append("name", "tmp");
```

now you'll see that `requests.files['file']` is filled with your file,
and `request.form` is filled with 'name' key and its value.

note that it's not the key name that fills `requests.files`, it is filled based on it's value (it should be file object)

you can create a structure like `name1` for `file1` metadata and `name2` for `file2` metadata.

Comment: That was best answer for this issue… It works for me!